# Sculpting Not Working Correctly, Only 1 Vertex able to Sculpt

Tags: sculpting

I am at a complete loss and trying to get the most basic of sculpting working. For now I'm just trying to take the basic Cylinder mesh and go to sculpting and draw squiggles onto the side of it so it looks indented, but whenever I left click nothing happens, the only thing I can do is slightly sculpt the top face of the cylinder making it wonky but I cant for the life of me get clay to draw on the top or the sides of the model. Screenshot provided.

[image: Only one vertex is being selected at a time]

Comment: sculpting needs topology, if your object has only a series of long vertical faces you will only be able to move the top or bottom vertices, unless you enable Dyntopo, which adds vertices

Comment: thank you really helped got it working